# row level locking trouble when using on date range

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I'm having following table structure.

```
 reservation: (InnoDB)
 ------------------------------------------
 id INT,
 date DATE,
 item_id INT,
 slot VARCHAR(50);
 PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE KEY(item_id,date).
```

Now i'm trying to use SELECT.....FOR UPDATE on reservation table inside a transaction to lock specific rows within date range(eg:2012-06-15 to 2012-06-16) of a particular item_id.

```
SELECT availability FROM reservation WHERE item_id={$item_id} AND (date>='{$to_date}' AND date<='{$from_date}') FOR UPDATE
```

NOW when i use the above statement, it is blocking all the rows of particular item_id even beyond the date range.I'm also using this UNIQUE KEY(item_id,date).

How to lock only particular date range of a specific item_id?

regards,
ravi.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$from_date` is 2012-06-15 and `$to_date` is 2012-06-16 you are actually selecting the outer range plus those dates, cause of the `=`s. Change your query to this:

```
SELECT availability FROM reservation 
WHERE item_id={$item_id} AND (date <= '{$to_date}' AND date >= '{$from_date}') 
FOR UPDATE;
```

**UPDATE:**

This

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting
>   transaction

means, that your query was aborted, cause another query is holding a lock on those rows for too long. Your best bet is to find out what / which query / transaction is causing this and try to speed this up. Maybe [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/03/08/how-to-debug-long-running-transactions-in-mysql/) helps.

If this doesn't help, you can try and increase the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable. Read more about it in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html).

Comment: Still getting following error when queried as you said.
mysql>  SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE studbike_id=1 AND date='2012-06-17' FOR
UPDATE;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: Actually i got timeout for date='2012-06-17' because i've set a SELECT...FOR UPDATE LOCK on range (date<='2012-06-16' AND date>='2012-06-15'). This exclusive lock not allowing to set a lock on date='2012-06-17' hence i'm getting timeout for transaction.

Comment: @ravi Um, that's what I was talking about? So see how you can solve this or post more info, maybe the whole transaction would be a good start.